# Is it possible to set different scale dependent visibility for one layer classifications?

Tags: qgis, layers, classification, scale, zoom

I'm working on a sewer and water network, so I need to set different scale visibility for primary, secondary and tertiary network.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use Rule based style to set the scale for primary, secondary and tertiary network, as you can see below (but with different data):

[image]

You can double-click each styled label to get more details:

[image]