# Apply scale dependency to point layer for only certain records in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

At 3.8.2, I have a point layer representing cities and towns.  As I zoom in I need the symbols and labels of smaller towns to appear.  As I zoom out I need them to disappear.  At the same time, the larger city symbols need to display at all scales.

I have successfully set the scale dependency for the **labels**, via *Layer Styling > Labels > Label Options, data-defined override.*  The smaller town labels appear and disappear as the mapscale changes, according to mapscale values in the attribute table.  The large city labels are on at all scales.

However, I cannot find a way to set data-defined override scale dependency for the point **symbols**.  Right now all town and city symbols are on at all scales.  I have searched through *Layer Styling > Symbology* to set the visibility scale for each point without success.

Comment: Have you checked this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210864/is-it-possible-to-set-different-scale-dependent-visibility-for-one-layer-classif/210866#210866?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the rule based symbologie to set a scale dependency

Just classify your point using the categorized renderer then change to the rule based renderer (this autofill all the rule so you dont have to set them manually), now just double click on any rule and set the Scale range as needed.

Comment: Perfect!  I did not have to use the categorized renderer first.  Instead, I went directly to the rule-based renderer.